# Javascript regex for validating name without accented characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm using a simple Javascript regular expression to validate people's names. However, I do not want to allow a user to enter accented characters like `ã`, `ä`, `õ`, `ö`, etc. I am aware that these can actually be valid characters in a name, but for my exercise, I need to be able to filter them out.

My current regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+('|-|.|)[a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

This matches accented characters as well. How do I modify this regex so that it doesn't match names with accents (or any Unicode character, for that matter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.`, because `.` match any character. That could cause matching accented character.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+('|-)[a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

or escape `.` if you mean literal dot.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+('|-|\.)[a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

Comment: You should also remove that last pipe character because it creates an empty (though harmless) character match between `|` and `)`.

Comment: @mart1n, I removed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To match a single character it's better to use a class `[...]`, not a group with alternatives `(...|...)`:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+['.-][a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

Note that this is not 100% accurate, since it validates things like `foo.bar` etc.